# Move DNS Records from Office 365 to AWS Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365, amazon-route53, ns-record

I am trying to move my DNS service over from Office365 to AWS Route 53. AWS was where the domain was purchased but due to the ease (at that point at least) the DNS entries were setup at Offce 365. I'm now trying to move them over to route 53 as we're launching some web services from that domain.
I've tried following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-at-aws?view=o365-worldwide but this seems to be if it's coming from the start. My domain is setup in full at AWS but

```
> dig -t ns mydoamin.com 
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydoamin.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns1.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
mydoamin.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns2.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
mydoamin.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns3.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
mydoamin.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns4.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
```

How do I delete these. Office 365 under the admin center -> settings -> Domain --> mydomain.com I only get the option to copy. I've also tried the 'remove domain' but that seems to be the delete.
Any help much appreciated. I have looked at other stackoverflow/server fault questions but none of them that I can see tell me how to get rid of the NS entries. Probably something obvious.

Comment: The article you linked in your question is about creating your Office 365 related DNS records in AWS when AWS is already hosting your DNS zone. Are you trying to move your DNS zone from Office 365 to AWS?

Comment: Yep. It's currently in O365 and I need to move to AWS route53. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay well after a lot of googling and nothing really helping I found the answer. I had everything moved over into AWS but I had forgotten that I had AWS NS pointing to microsoft. So there really wasn't anything to do in microsoft.
A lot of me forgetting and not being a network guy! Also have to say AWS sort of hides it.
Anyways incase someone else is having the same issues -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html